# A question regarding recurrence relations

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that for all $n \geq 1$ ,
$$a_{n+3}+ra_{n+2}+sa_{n+1}+ta_n=0$$ It is given that the equation $$x^3+rx^2+sx+t=0...(1)$$ has solutions $\alpha =\beta \neq \gamma$. Show that $(b_n)_{n \geq 1}$ defined by $$b_n=(n-1)\alpha^{n-1}$$ satisfies the same recurrence relation as $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$.
My attempt: Since $\alpha$ is the root of the eq.(1), we get that,
$$\alpha^3+r\alpha^2+s\alpha+t=0$$and thus by induction,we can show that $$\alpha^{k+3}+r\alpha^{k+2}+s\alpha^{k+1}+\alpha^k=0$$ for all $k \geq 1$. After that I kept manipulating this to get the result such multiplying $3$ to both sides and so and so. I also noticed that if I show that $$b_{4}+rb_{3}+sb_{2}+tb_{1}=0$$ then the whole thing gets done. Because, if it is true,for any $k \geq 1$ we get that if
$$ b_{k+3}+rb_{k+2}+sb_{k+1}+tb_{k}=0\Rightarrow  (k+2)\alpha^{k+2}+r(k+1)\alpha^{k+1}+sk\alpha^{k}+t\alpha^{k-1}(k-1)=0.$$ Multiplying $\alpha$ to both sides and adding $\alpha^{k+3}+r\alpha^{k+2}+s\alpha^{k+1}+t\alpha^k$ to both sides we get,
$$(k+2)\alpha^{k+2}+r(k+1)\alpha^{k+1}+sk\alpha^{k}+t\alpha^{k-1}(k-1)=0 \Rightarrow \alpha[(k+2)\alpha^{k+2}+r(k+1)\alpha^{k+1}+sk\alpha^{k}+t\alpha^{k-1}(k-1)]=0=(k+2)\alpha^{k+3}+r(k+1)\alpha^{k+2}+sk\alpha^{k+1}+t\alpha^{k}(k-1) \Rightarrow (k+2)\alpha^{k+3}+\alpha^{k+3}+r(k+1)\alpha^{k+2}+r\alpha^{k+2}+sk\alpha^{k+1}+s\alpha^{k+1}+t\alpha^{k}(k-1)+t\alpha^k=0+\alpha^{k+3}+r\alpha^{k+2}+s\alpha^{k+1}+t\alpha^k=0+0=0  $$ and thus, $$(k+3)\alpha^{k+3}+r(k+2)\alpha^(k+2)+s(k+1)\alpha^{k+1}+tk\alpha^k=0 \Rightarrow b_{k+4}+rb_{k+3}+sb_{k+2}+tb_{k+1}=0$$.Thus, if I can prove that$$b_{4}+rb_{3}+sb_{2}+tb_{1}=0$$ then then the result will follow by induction. But I can't find how. Please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing step in OP's attempt is making use of the condition that $\,\alpha=\beta\,$ is a double root.

Let $P(x)=x^3+rx^2+sx+t$, then $\alpha$ being a double root means $P(\alpha)=P'(\alpha)=0$, and so:

$$
\begin{align}
b_{n+3}+rb_{n+2}+sb_{n+1}+tb_n &= (n+2)\alpha^{n+2}+r(n+1)\alpha^{n+1}+sn\alpha^{n}+t(n-1)\alpha^{n-1}
\\ &= \alpha^{n-1}(n-1)\underbrace{\left(\alpha^3+r\alpha^2+s\alpha+t\right)}_{\displaystyle=P(\alpha)=0}+\alpha^n\underbrace{\left(3\alpha^2+2r\alpha+s\right)}_{\displaystyle =P'(\alpha)=0}
\\ &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I could not deduce $P'(\alpha) =0$

Comment: I have proved it some how.Let me know if there are any mistake.

Comment: $$3\alpha^3+2r\alpha^2+s\alpha=\alpha^3+r\alpha^2+s\alpha+2\alpha^3+r\alpha^2$$

Comment: Thus,$ -t+\alpha^2(2\alpha+r)=-t+ \alpha^2(2\alpha-2\alpha-\gamma)=-t+\alpha^2(-\gamma)=-t-\alpha^2\gamma=-t+t=0$ as $-r=2\alpha+\gamma$ and $-t=\alpha^2\gamma$

Comment: @queen_of_fat_blobs A root of $P$ has [multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial) greater than $1$ iff it is also a root of its derivative $P'$, see for example (the answers to) [Relation between root of a function and its derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33874/relation-between-root-of-a-function-and-its-derivative).

Comment: Sorry,I am not acquainted with Calculus fully.

Comment: I thought $P'$ was another polynomial

Comment: @queen_of_fat_blobs It may be a bit more tedious, but this can also be proved using just $P(x)=(x-\alpha)^2Q(x)$ and the definition of the formal derivative where $\left( x^k\right)^{'}=kx^{k-1}$ etc, which does not involve limits or calculus.